# Make UIPanGestureRecognizer stretch when pulling past certain threshold

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I'm trying to implement something similar to how Mac/iOS web pages are implemented, where if you pull past a certain threshold, the main view becomes "stretchy" and moves based on the velocity of the pull.

The difference, though, is I'm trying to do this horizontally for UITableViewCells with a UIPanGestureRecognizer.

I've got a `handlePan` method:

```
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    [recognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
    CGPoint velocity = [recognizer velocityInView:self];

    int panDelta = ([recognizer locationInView:self].x - [recognizer locationInView:self.superview].x);

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        _originalCenter = self.center;
    }

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

        CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self];

        float xVal = 0;
        if (panDelta <= 38) {
            xVal = _originalCenter.x + translation.x;
        } /*else {


           // this is where I struggle.


            xVal = _originalCenter.x;
        }*/
        self.center = CGPointMake(xVal, _originalCenter.y);

    }

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        CGRect newFrame;
        int xOffset = 0;

        newFrame = CGRectMake(xOffset, self.frame.origin.y,
                                          self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
            self.frame = newFrame;
        }];
    }
}
```

I don't have any specific algorithm to create the "stretchiness"; all I'm trying to do is make it so the sliding doesn't go as wide as the user's interaction is, and is fluid.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a simple function with a horizontal asymptote indicating a maximum offset:

```
// this is where I struggle.
CGFloat maxOffset = 50.0; // change as you like
CGFloat elementWidth = ?; // fill in the width of your view animated, eg: self.frame.size.width
CGFloat absPannedOffset = fabsf(translation.x);
CGFloat rico = powf(elementWidth, 2) / maxOffset;
CGFloat absOffset = (((- 1 / rico) * powf(absPannedOffset - elementWidth, 2)) + maxOffset);

if (pannedOffset < 0) {
    xVal = -absOffset;
} else {
    xVal = absOffset;
}
```